# Within Spring roo, why an addon installation hangs (not downloading anything)?

Tags: spring, git, installation

Find here below the script : 
roo> addon search git 
roo> addon install id --searchResultId 01

then, roo hangs there. Nothing happened. It stays there for a long time.

My OS is Win8/64bits.
Is there any way to download and then install the addon manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to run roo using command line not the one under STS.
Downloading addon works better under command line